# Como mover uma ImageView no android studio

Tags: android

Olá, estou tentando fazer a movimentação de uma ImageView do centro da tela para a parte de cima, e não estou conseguindo.

Efeito desejado: A logo começa no centro e vai para uma posição na parte de cima da tela ao iniciar a activity.

Já tentei muita coisa, esse foi o primeiro: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11144421/move-an-imageview-to-different-position-in-animated-way-in-android mas o problema de usar TranslateAnimation é que todo final de animação ele volta para o lugar de inicio.

Já tentei usar ObjectAnimator, ele até faz o movimento que preciso e para no lugar, só que não começa a partir do centro e sim da parte de cima da tela.

### **RESOLVIDO**

[Resposta](https://www.includehelp.com/android/move-image-on-a-particular-axis.aspx)

Comment: Coloque na pergunta o código que tentou.

Comment: Enfim encontrei: [link](https://www.includehelp.com/android/move-image-on-a-particular-axis.aspx) agora só preciso fazer isso ao iniciar a tela e não quando clicar no botão.